# AWS s3 presigned url not downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download file from S3 pre Signed URL.I am getting access denied error The url looks like this.

```
https://s3.us.amazonaws.com/test1/xxxxxxxx
```

Here my python code.

```
def getfile(self, url):
   url2 = str(url).replace("['", "")
   s3 = boto3.client('s3')
   key = "xxxxxxxxxxdd"
   filename = "file_name.hex"
   s3.download_file(key, url2, filename)
```

The file is created in my disk. But looks like this.

```
 <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid date (should be seconds since epoch): 1666657825']</Message><RequestId>DDNEB34VSFF124GT</RequestId><HostId>Rby3Bz/pqz2p6l7nMf4=</HostId></Error>%
```

Any help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can't alter a pre-signed URL to do things like change the filename. You must use as-is.

Comment: I am not altering any file names. In local file save I am giving the file name

Comment: You are altering the URL, for some reason, and appear to be leaving a stray `']` in the URL that certainty did not come from a proper signing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you generate pre signed url like this:

```
 s3.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params = {'Bucket': 'bucket-1', 'Key': key},
    ExpiresIn = SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT
)
```

Make sure ExpiresIn is in seconds

For more : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

**or,**

Use this format: **`https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>`**

```
url = 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/' + key
```

Comment: `ExpiresIn` is seconds, like "60".  It is not an offset from the epoch.

Comment: Since I already have presigned url. Can I directly download with boto3?